# about plotting two images in pseudocolor figures

Tags: matlab, color-mapping

I am using matlab to visualize my data in pseudocolor figures (`pcolor`). It works pretty good to show the data in pcolor but now I get one more data set. If I plot each data set in a separate pcolor plot, everything is fine. But now, I combine the two data such that

```
NEW_DATA = [OLDDATA1, OLDATA2]
```

if I pcolor the NEW_DATA instead, the color get messed up. Is that any way I can show the combined data without losing any detail or color information. In my case, if you plot `pcolor(NEW_DATA)`, the general shape was maintained (just like `[pcolor(OLDDATA1), pcolor(OLDATA2)]`) but some detail become fuzzy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [pcolor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/pcolor.html) plots, the vertex colors are scaled into the color map.  You can set the scaling using the `'clim'` property of the axes.  I'm guessing what is happening here is that the scaling is different between the two `OLDDATA` and the combined `NEWDATA`.

Ultimately you need to decide which scaling to use; if you like the original from `OLDDATA1`, you could do the following:

```
pcolor(OLDDATA1);
orig_clim = get(gca,'clim'); %# just to get the color limits

pcolor(NEWDATA);
set(gca, 'clim', orig_clim);
```

If you like the original scaling of *both* `OLDDATA` plots and there isn't a scaling that works for both, you can manually create a figure with two axes placed adjacent to each other (rather than relying on `subplot`).  Each axes object can have its own `clim` that way, but the two plots will appear contiguous.

```
figure;
h1 = axes('units','normalized','position',[.05 .05 .45 .45]);
h2 = axes('units','normalized','position',[.5  .05 .45 .45]);
pcolor(h1, OLDDATA1);
pcolor(h2, OLDDATA2);
set(h2, 'ytick', []); %# turn off ytick (if it was on)
```